# z-index is not working when script send from controller to jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm having a problem to set z-index between image and div (i prepare this div to save the edit (reupload new image) and delete button. 
for your information i'm using ajax and codeigniter to handle an image upload, and after the image uploaded, i want to view the image with the edit and delete button on it.
and this is my html

```
<div class="writecontainer">
    <div class="dropable">
        <input class="ufile" type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="file"/>
        <p class="italic tcenter" style="margin-top:-120px;color:#a6a6a6;z-index:0">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/login/2camera48.png';?>"/>
            <br>
            click or drop your image here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css style

```
.writecontainer{
    margin-top:30px;
    width:600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.dropable{
    background:#e0ebeb;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.writecontainer > .dropable > img.uploadtemp{
    width:100%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.writecontainer .dropable input.ufile{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

and the ajax (jquery)

```
$('#file').on('change',function(){
    var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost/login/index.php/dashboard_main/upload_file', 
       dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       data: form_data,
       type: 'post',
       success: function (response) {

       $('.dropable').html(response);
       $('.dropable').removeAttr('style');
       $(".dropable").css("height:auto");
       $(".dropable div.editcontainer").css({"z-index":"99"});
       $(".dropable > img").css({"z-index":"-1"});
       },
       error: function (response) {
       alert(response);
       }
    });
});
```

and the method in the controller is

```
public function upload_file() {
    $xx['userData'] = $this->session->userdata('userData');
    //upload file
    $config['upload_path'] = 'images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_filename'] = '5000000';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['max_size'] = '1024000'; //1 MB
    $config['file_name'] = $xx['userData']['oauth_uid'].'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

    if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        //$new = 'xyz'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
            if (file_exists('images/' . $config['file_name'])) {
                echo 'File already exists in the desire destination';
            } else {
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                } else {
                    echo '<img class="uploadtemp" src="'.base_url().'images/' . $config['file_name'].'"><div class="editcontainer" style="height:45px; margin-top:-50px;border:1px solid red;"></div>';

                }
            }
        //echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
    } else {
        echo 'Image upload unsuccessful';
    }
}
```

first, i set z-index in controller, but nothing happen. so i think maybe it must be set after i print out the html data in ajax, but z-index still error. any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: remove that `{ }` curly braces around your .css() function and check again.

Comment: according to your suggestion i try it, but nothing happen
this is the code

    $(".dropable div.editcontainer").css("z-index":"99");
    $(".dropable > img").css("z-index":"-1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an html in ajax from your controller, just add the css in the style tag like this and add !important. z-index: 9999 !important. Example `z-index: 9999 !important`

```
  echo '<img class="uploadtemp" src="'.base_url().'images/' . $config['file_name'].'"><div class="editcontainer" style="height:45px; margin-top:-50px;border:1px solid red;z-index: 9999 !importantz-index: 9999 !important"></div>';
```